# References to elements in vectors during construction

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference, stdvector

In C++, I have a class `MyClass`, which during construction takes a reference to an `int` to create an internal reference to it.

I then have a class `BigClass`, containing both an `std::vector<int> vecInt_` and an `std::vector<MyClass> vecMyClass_`. The constructor of `BigClass` takes as an argument the size of the vectors `vecInt_` and `vecMyClass_`. In the constructor of `BigClass`, I would like to have each element of `vecMyClass_` use in its constructor the corresponding element of `vecInt_`.

How could I write that ? If I could call the constructors of `vecMyClass` from the body of the constructor of BigClass, that would look like that :

```
BigClass(int nbElem) :
    vecInt_(nbElem),
    vecMyClass_(nbElem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nbElem; ++i)
    {
        vecMyClass_[i](vecMyInt_[i]);
    }
}
```

But of course the parenthesis here would mean `operator()`, and not the constructor. I cannot write something like:

```
vecMyClass_[i] = MyClass(vecMyInt_[i]);
```

Because MyClass contains a reference and not a pointer, and thus referenced value can not be modified.

Comment: Do `vecInt_` and `vecMyClass_` have to be `const`?

Comment: No elements of the vector will be added / removed, however the values stored in the vector will be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize `vecMyClass_` as an empty vector and `emplace_back` elements into it while you construct them:

```
BigClass(int nbElem) :
    vecInt_(nbElem),
    vecMyClass_() //empty vector
{
    vecMyClass_.reserve(nbElem); //avoid reallocations
    for (int i = 0; i < nbElem; ++i)
    {
        vecMyClass_.emplace_back(vecInt_[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like a very good idea. At some point adding elements to vecMyInt_ will result in expanding the vector, i.e. allocating new memory and moving the elements there, and freeing the old memory. This means that the references kept by instances of MyClass will be invalid.

Of course this won't be a problem if you reserve the capacity beforehand, and never add elements to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {
  int& x;
  MyClass(int& x) : x(x) {}
};

struct BigClass {
  BigClass(std::size_t nb_elems) : ints(nb_elems) {
    my_classes.reserve(nb_elems);
    for(int& x : ints) {
      my_classes.emplace_back(x);
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> ints;
  std::vector<MyClass> my_classes;
};

int main()
{
  BigClass b{10};
  for(int& x : b.ints) {
    x = 23;
  }

  // they are all 23
  for(auto& c : b.my_classes) {
    std::cout << c.x << std::endl;
    // change them
    c.x = 24;
  }

  // they are all 24 now
  for(auto& c : b.ints) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```